# How does the isDirty flag work with vscode.custom document

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been asked to add a button to our vscode app that deploys any files created by our own internal custom editors built using vscode.customdocument not textdocument.

How do I check a customdocument is dirty, if I call vscode.workspace.textDocument or use vscode.workspace.opentextdocument its always false even if the dirty indicator is showing dirty in the UI.

Comment: Please be sure to add appropriate tags to your question to be sure the right people see the question; not every JavaScript expert knows about Visual Studio Code development (and I'm guessing it's about working with extensions).

Comment: Oh sorry assumed that was automatic as it was a link from vscode GitHub, oh you have done it thanks